# DiscordAPI Error 10002 Unknown Application

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

i can't find the problem why the error appears. I checked both ID (GUILD, BOT) but I can't see why he will not accept this.

Do I have to map it to a file?

```
const { REST, Routes, SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');


const commands = [
    {
        name: 'bier',
        description: 'Antwortet mit Krug oder Fass?',
    },
];

const rest = new REST ({ version: '10' }).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log('Nehme Bestellung auf!');

        await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationGuildCommands(process.env.GUILD_ID, process.env.BOT_ID),
            { body: commands }
        )

        console.log('Bestellung wurde aufgenommen!')
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Bier ist aus! ${error}`);
    }
})();


===========================================

ERROR: > node commands/bier.js
Nehme Bestellung auf!
Bier ist aus! DiscordAPIError[10002]: Unknown Application
```

Comment: EDIT: changed version: '10' => 'v10', still getting an error. Now it´s just 
DiscordAPIError[0]: 404: Not Found

Comment: The error means that your application ID is wrong, check if you've set the correct environment value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just restarted the Bot in the Discord Dev Portal, and deleted the 'v' before the 10. Now it works!